# How to get Node properties as a map from Neo4j driver

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm struggling to get data in the way I need it from the native driver (jdbcTemplate did this for me out of the box).

My code:

```
List<Record> result = session.run(cql,params).list();
return result.stream()
    .map(record -> record.asMap())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This returns a List<Map<String, Object>> which is kind of what I need except the Object here is of type InternalNode.

What I really want is for this Object itself to be a Map<String, Object> where the keys and values are the node properties. I just can't figure out the interfaces and various asMap method etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your Cypher query, this is a little bit hard to grasp.
I assume based on your result, that you have something like:

```
MATCH (n:Node) return n;
```

The resulting record will be indeed `("n", InternalNode)`.
This means that calling the `asMap()` on the `record` just serialises the result into a map without conversion of the containing values.
What you could do, depending on your return pattern, is to explicitly ask for the node first and then call the `asMap()` function.

```
var cql = "MATCH (n:Node) return n";
List<Record> result = session.run(cql).list();
var resultListMap = result.stream()
                    .map(record -> record.get("n").asMap())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would then result in a list of maps containing the "flat" properties.

Another way of doing this without the extraction of the node first is

```
var resultListMap = result.stream()
                    .map(record -> record.asMap(value -> value.asMap()))
    // or short     .map(record -> record.asMap(MapAccessor::asMap))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where for every value in the map the `asMap()` gets called.

Comment: thanks I did figure out something similar eventually